# How to write the information related to referees in an application form?

Tags: application, recommendation-letter

What's the best way to give information about the person who's going to give recommendation letter, in an application form?

> John Clark, Ph.D. in Physics and Mathematics
>
> Associate Professor
>
> Teacher of 'Web Programming' course during the 6th semester
>
> Email address: email.address@example.com
>
> Telephone Number: +00 1234 5678

Is there any need for the 3rd line, at all? Do I need to add information related to the department the person is working in?

Comment: What does the form say to provide?

Comment: "State the name, position/title/profession, organisation, contact information, and relation to the applicant of two people who can provide recommendations."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like you've left out the "organization" and the mailing address. I'd change line 2 to something like: "Associate Professor, Department of Physics, The University of Exampleville". Then you should add several lines below the telephone number that gives the work mailing address of your recommender. If they can't provide that to you directly, you can almost certainly provide the departmental mailing address which should be on their website.

Comment: Thank you. Do you think having "Teacher of 'Web Programming' course during the 6th semester" is correct? And is it the best way to word it like that? What if the teacher has been involved in more than one courses? In that case, is writing something like: "Teacher on several courses including: [...]" acceptable?

Comment: "[R]elation to the applicant" seems to encompass the listing of courses that the recommender has taught to the applicant. Your wording is fine. You're not going to be judged in or out by the very precise word choice on how your recommender knows you as long as it's clear what the relationship is.